# tags search with amazon cloudsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, amazon-cloudsearch

I have products that are tagged with keywords. Tags are not unique to any products.

product 1 - tag1, tag2, tag3

product 2 - tag2, tag3

product 3 - tag1, tag2, tag4

I intend to use Amazon Cloudsearch for a start. What is the optimal way to populate the dataset, as well as to perform the tags search? The query may have multiple tags to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your schema should consist of

- product_id: `literal` or `text` field, depending on how you want to search it
- tags: `literal-array` or `text-array` field

Have a look at this guide, which covers the basics of mapping your data to a search document: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/preparing-data.html

This guide covers basic searching, to answer the second part of your question: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/submitting-search-requests.html

Give that a try and let us know if you have any specific questions. Your use-case appears to be very straightforward and will be covered in those tutorials.